# JS AJAX scope issue

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am getting id of undefined_content and i cannot find why.

I am guessing scope but i cannot see where i am wrong here.

`var extraInfoHTML` is the point that gets the undefined id and rowID the variable that's undefined.

```
   $(function(){
     var rowID;

        $('.entryx').on('click', function(rowID){
            pid = $(this).attr('profileid');
            rowID = $(this).attr('id');

            $('.additionInfo_dropDown').hide();
            $(this).after("<tr class='additionInfo_dropDown'><td colspan=6>"+extraInfoHTML+"</td></tr>");

         populateExtra(rowID , pid);



         //alert(derp);
        });

    var extraInfoHTML = "<div id='"+ rowID +"_content' class='profileInfoDropDown'>"+
                        "DERPINGTONS"+
                        "</div>";               
    });

function populateExtra(rowID , pid) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "admin_populate_profile.php",
      data: { rowID : rowID,
              pid: pid
            }
    }).success(function(datareturn) { 
        idx = rowID +'_content';
        $("#"+idx).html(datareturn);
        alert(datareturn);
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `extraInfoHTML` is set in the `document.ready` event. In other words, the text is contatenated and `rowId` evaluated before you assign any value to it. You are assigning a value to `rowId` only in the `.entryx` click event handler.

Changing the order might solve that:

```
  $(function(){
     var rowID;

     $('.entryx').on('click', function(rowID){
       pid = $(this).attr('profileid');
       rowID = $(this).attr('id');
       var extraInfoHTML = "<div id='"+ rowID +"_content' class='profileInfoDropDown'>"+
                        "DERPINGTONS"+
                        "</div>";    
       $('.additionInfo_dropDown').hide();
       $(this).after("<tr class='additionInfo_dropDown'><td colspan=6>"+extraInfoHTML+"</td></tr>");

         populateExtra(rowID , pid);
         //alert(derp);
        });    
    });
```